# Display table based on user's selection

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I'd like to show the car list corresponding to the user's selection on the drop-down list. Let's say, if they select SUV, then the table of SUV cars will show up. Somehow, my code doesn't seem to be working. When I select all, it's fine - but other than that, it shows nothing.

What did I do wrong? I suspect that I went wrong in the event handler when I call `displayListing`.

```js
//step-1: add jQuery ready method to hold entire js code in this script 
$(document).ready(function(){

// Define a car object using a constructor function
function Car(id, car_make, car_model, car_year, car_type, car_color, car_price, car_mileage) {
 this.stockid = id;
 this.make = car_make;
 this.model = car_model;
 this.year = car_year;
 this.type = car_type;
 this.color = car_color;
 this.price = car_price;
 this.mileage = car_mileage;
 this.qty = 0; 
 this.display = function(){
  var this_str = "<td>" + this.stockid + "</td><td>" + this.make + "</td>";
  this_str += "<td>" + this.model + "</td><td>" + this.year + "</td><td>" + this.type + "</td>";
  this_str += "<td>" + this.color + "</td><td>$" + this.price + "</td>";
  this_str += "<td>" + this.mileage + "</td>";
  
  return this_str;
 }
}

// Declare an array of objects
var car_list = [];  // var car_list = new Array();

// Create an instance of the Car object and add it to the car_list array
car_list.push(new Car(1001, "Toyota", "Camry", 2011, "Sedan", "Gray", 17555, 55060));
car_list.push(new Car(1002, "Volvo", "s40", 2013, "Sedan", "Black", 15575, 20350));
car_list.push(new Car(1251, "Toyota", "Sienna", 2008, "Minivan", "Gray", 15775, 70000));
car_list.push(new Car(1321, "Porsche", "Panamera", 2012, "SUV", "Red", 104250, 10567));
car_list.push(new Car(1904, "Honda", "Accord", 2009, "Sedan", "White", 13370, 35000));
car_list.push(new Car(1855, "Toyota", "Highlander", 2008, "SUV", "Silver", 18555, 55060));
car_list.push(new Car(1543, "Ford", "Fusion", 2011, "Sedan", "Black", 13575, 90350));
car_list.push(new Car(1345, "Toyota", "Sienna", 2011, "Minivan", "Gray", 25775, 70000));
car_list.push(new Car(2133, "Dodge", "Caravan", 2012, "Minivan", "Red", 30250, 17567));
car_list.push(new Car(2999, "Lexus", "LFA", 2012, "coupe", "Red", 381370, 3500));
car_list.push(new Car(3001, "Ferrari", "Rubino", 2012, "coupe", "Red", 354370, 5500));
car_list.push(new Car(4002, "Audi", "R8", 2012, "SUV", "Black", 181370, 4500));


//Step-2 (a): call displayDropdown() function to set up the drop down selection list
displayDropdown();

//Step-2 (d): use jQuery event method .on() to add an event handler to the drop down list
//so that when users change selection option based on car type, 
//then only that type of cars will be displayed in the car list table in the web page.
$('#car-category').on('change', function(){
 var cat = $(this).val();
 console.log(cat);
 displayListing(cat);
} );


/*****************************/
/* displayDropdown()         */
/*****************************/ 
function displayDropdown(){
 var currentCat = 'select';
 var output = "<option value=\'"+ currentCat + "\'>Select a category to display</option>";
 var addedCats = [];

//Step-3 (a): add script code here to add options to the drop down list
 for(var i = 0; i < car_list.length; i++) {
  currentCat = car_list[i].type;
  //check whether the car's type has been included in the drop down list, if not, then add that category to the list
  //Array.indexOf(currentItem) is used to check whether currentItem is in the array, if not, then -1 will be returned.
  if (addedCats.indexOf(currentCat)==-1) { //did not find currentCat in addedCats array
   addedCats.push(currentCat); //add currentCat to addedCats array, and then create
   //an <option> element for that category
   output += "<option value='" + currentCat + "'  class='cat-select'>" + currentCat + "</option>";
//console.log("added " + currentCat);
  } 
//console.log(addedCats);
 } // end for loop
 //add one more category as an <option> element which is used to display all products 
 currentCat = "All";
 output += "<option value='" + currentCat + "'  class='cat-select'>" + currentCat + "</option>";
// output is a string used to hold all new <option> elements 
 $('#car-category').html(output);

 }
 
/*****************************/
/* displayListing()          */
/*****************************/  
 function displayListing(cat){
 //Step-2 (b): Add jQuery code in this function to remove class "hide" from car list table.  
 $('#car-list').removeClass('hide');
 var displayAll = false;
 if (cat == "All") {
  displayAll = true;
 } 
 if (cat == "select") {
   $('#car-list tbody').html("");
 }
 var body="";
 
   //add table body 
   //step-2 (c):add js code to complete the for loop and if statement  to display car list in the web page according to 
   //users’ selection on car type
   for(var i = 0; i < car_list.length; i++) {
  if(car_list[i].category == cat || displayAll == true) {
   console.log("add table list: " + cat);
   body += "<tr class='car-item' id='l-"+ i + "'>";  
   body += car_list[i].display();
   body += "<td><button type='button' value='" + 
   i + "' class='btn btn-primary add-item'>Add</button></td>";  
   body += "</tr>";
  }
 }
 $('#car-list tbody').html(body);
 }

//define an array (global variable) to store indices of the items added to the shopping cart*/
 var cart = [];
 

//Step-3 (a): Apply jQuery event delegation technique to add event handler so that when users click Add buttons, 
//the selected cars will be added to the shopping cart without any duplication, 
//the selected cars’ information including stockid, make, model, price, quantity and type will be displayed 
//in the shopping cart list on the web page, the number of items in the shopping cart as well as the Checkout 
//invoice information including subtotal, tax, registration fee, and total amount will be updated.
 $('#car_list').on('click', '.add-item', function(){
       var index = $(this).val(); 
       if (cart.indexOf(index)== -1)
       {  cart.push(index); 
//console.log("Cart array is currently: " + cart);
       }
       addQty(index); 
       updateShoppingCart();} );
/****************/
/* addQty()     */
/****************/
function addQty(index) {
 car_list[index].qty++;
}


/*****************************/
/* updateShoppingCart()      */
/*****************************/
 function updateShoppingCart(){
//step 3(b): Add jQuery code in this function to remove class "hide" from shopping cart table, 
//and also from check out table. 
    $('#cart table').removeClass('hide');
 $('#checkout table').removeClass('hide');
 
//console.log("Cart array is currently: " + cart);
 //display shopping cart 
 displayCartItems();

 // update total items
 updateItemTotal();

 //Update final checkout data
 calculateCheckoutCost();

 }
 
 /**************************/
/* displayCartItems()     */
/**************************/
function displayCartItems(){
 /* use this method to display items in the shopping cart.
 This method should  redisplay the 'shopping cart'
 table when we add or delete items.*/
 // add each product to shopping cart
 var runError = true;
 var elm='';
 for (var i=0; i<cart.length; i++){
   //create a table row and add stockId, make, cost, quantity, and type info of the selected cars to the cart table
   elm += "<tr><td class=\'col-xs-1\'>"+ car_list[cart[i]].stockid + "</td>";
   elm += "<td class=\'col-xs-1\'>"+ car_list[cart[i]].make + "</td>";
   elm += "<td class=\'col-xs-1\'>"+ car_list[cart[i]].model + "</td>";
   elm += "<td class=\'col-xs-1\'>"+ car_list[cart[i]].price + "</td>";
   elm += "<td class=\'col-xs-1\'><input  type=\'text\' id=\'" + cart[i] + "\' name=\'qty-" + i +
   "\' size=\'1\' value=\'"+ car_list[cart[i]].qty + "\'></td>";
   elm += "<td class=\'col-xs-1\'>"+ car_list[cart[i]].type + "</td>";
   elm += "<td class=\'col-xs-1\'><button type=\'button\' value=\'" + i + "\' class=\'delete-item\'>Delete</button></td></tr>";
   runError = false; // = cart is not empty
 }
 if (runError) { //if cart is empty
  elm += "Your cart is empty.";
 }
 //step 3(d): add a jQuery selector 
//console.log(elm); 
 $('#mycart tbody').html(elm); // modify the table
}


/*****************************/
/* updateItemTotal()         */
/*****************************/
 function updateItemTotal(){
 // update the total items
 var total = cart.length;
 $('#items').text(total);
 } 

/*******************************/
/* calculateCheckoutCost()     */
/*******************************/
function calculateCheckoutCost(){

 //Display total number of cars in the cart 
 var taxRate = 0.06;
 var feeRate = 0.05;
 var subtotal = 0;
 var tax = 0;
 var fee = 0;
 var total = 0;
 
 //Calculate subtotal 
 var subtotal = 0;
 //step 6: add js code here to calculat subtotal, tax, fee, and total amount
 //display those information to web page by using jQuery selector, jQuery .text() method.
  
}
//Step-4: Apply jQuery event delegation technique to add event handler so that when users click Delete buttons 
//the selected cars will be removed from the shopping cart and removed from the shopping cart list in the web page as well. 
//Meanwhile, the number of items in the shopping cart as well as the Checkout invoice information including subtotal, tax, 
//registration fee, and total amount will be updated.





/*****************************/
/* deleteItemFromCart()      */
/*****************************/
 function deleteItemFromCart(index){
 /*  remove the element with a given index from the cart array and update shopping cart
  use splice() method, Syntax: array_name.splice(start, how many elements)
 The splice() method removes elements starting from 'start' positions. The second arguments defines the number of elements to be removed.
 */
   //step 3(f): add script to update the ordering quantity of selected car and use splice method to 
   //remove that selected car from the shopping cart.
    car_list[cart[index]].qty = 0;
 cart.splice(index, 1);
}

//Step-5: Apply jQuery event delegation technique to add event handler so that when users change the ordering 
//quantities of selected cars in the shopping list in the web page, 
//the ordering quantities of selected cars the Checkout invoice information including subtotal, tax, registration fee,
// and total amount will be updated. 





/*****************************/
/* updateCartItemQty()       */
/*****************************/
 function updateCartItemQty(input) {
 var value = 0;
 value = parseInt($("#" + input.id).val());

 var index = parseInt(input.id); 
 car_list[index].qty = value;
 
 }

 


 
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Auto Shop - Used Cars</title>
    <!--Include bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
 <!-- Include JQuery library --> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
 <!-- Include external js file (JQuery_auto_shop.js) here -->
<script src="JQuery_auto_shop.js"></script>

 <style>
   td{ padding: 5px; margin: 5px;}
  .addme { height: 28px; width: 80px; padding: 0; }
  .clm-label { background: #333; color: #fff;}
  .hide {display: none} 
 </style>
 
</head>
<body class='container'>
 <div class='col-md-9' >
    <h2>Choose a car type </h2> <!--drop down list -->
 <select id="car-category" name="car-category">
  <option value='null'>Loading....</option>
 </select>
 </div>
 <div class='col-md-9'>
    <h2>Car List</h2> <!-- car list -->
  <table class='table hide' id='car-list'>
  <thead><!--car list table header -->
  <tr class='clm-label'> 
     <th class='clm-label'>Stock ID</th>
     <th class='clm-label'>Make</th>
     <th class='clm-label'>Model</th>
     <th class='clm-label'>Year</th>
     <th class='clm-label'>Type</th>
     <th class='clm-label'>Color</th>
     <th class='clm-label'>Price</th>
     <th class='clm-label'>Mileage</th>
     <th class='clm-label'>Select</th>
   </tr>  
   </thead>
   <tbody id='car-list'><!--car list table body -->
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
 <div class='col-md-3' id="cart">
  <h2>Shopping Cart</h2>
  <div>You have <span id="items">0</span>  items in your Shopping Cart</div>
  <table class='table hide' id='mycart'><!--Shopping Cart list table -->
  <thead><!--table header -->
   <tr>
    <th class='clm-label'>Stock Id</th>
    <th class='clm-label'>Make</th>
    <th class='clm-label'>Model</th>
    <th class='clm-label'>Price</th>
    <th class='clm-label'>Quantity</th>
    <th class='clm-label'>Type</th>
    <th class='clm-label'></th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody><!--table body -->
  </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>

<div class='col-md-9' id="checkout">
    <h2>Check Out</h2>
 <table class='table hide' ><!--Check Out table -->
  <tr><th class='col-xs-4'>Subtotal: </th><td class='col-xs-2' id='sub-total'>0</td></tr>
  <tr><th class='col-xs-4'>Taxes (6%): </th><td class='col-xs-2' id='taxes'>0</td></tr>
  <tr><th class='col-xs-4'>Registration fee (5%): </th><td class='col-xs-2' id='registration'>0</td></tr>
  <tr><th class='col-xs-4'>Total due: </th><td class='col-xs-2' id='total'>0</td></tr>
 </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using the wrong attribute in your displayListing() function.

this line:

```
if(car_list[i].category == cat || displayAll == true) {
```

you are using car_list[i].category when it should be car_list[i].type.

The Car object doesn't have an attribute called category. You should change the line to look like this:

```
if(car_list[i].type == cat || displayAll == true) {
```

here is the complete snippet:

```js
//step-1: add jQuery ready method to hold entire js code in this script 
$(document).ready(function(){

// Define a car object using a constructor function
function Car(id, car_make, car_model, car_year, car_type, car_color, car_price, car_mileage) {
 this.stockid = id;
 this.make = car_make;
 this.model = car_model;
 this.year = car_year;
 this.type = car_type;
 this.color = car_color;
 this.price = car_price;
 this.mileage = car_mileage;
 this.qty = 0; 
 this.display = function(){
  var this_str = "<td>" + this.stockid + "</td><td>" + this.make + "</td>";
  this_str += "<td>" + this.model + "</td><td>" + this.year + "</td><td>" + this.type + "</td>";
  this_str += "<td>" + this.color + "</td><td>$" + this.price + "</td>";
  this_str += "<td>" + this.mileage + "</td>";
  
  return this_str;
 }
}

// Declare an array of objects
var car_list = [];  // var car_list = new Array();

// Create an instance of the Car object and add it to the car_list array
car_list.push(new Car(1001, "Toyota", "Camry", 2011, "Sedan", "Gray", 17555, 55060));
car_list.push(new Car(1002, "Volvo", "s40", 2013, "Sedan", "Black", 15575, 20350));
car_list.push(new Car(1251, "Toyota", "Sienna", 2008, "Minivan", "Gray", 15775, 70000));
car_list.push(new Car(1321, "Porsche", "Panamera", 2012, "SUV", "Red", 104250, 10567));
car_list.push(new Car(1904, "Honda", "Accord", 2009, "Sedan", "White", 13370, 35000));
car_list.push(new Car(1855, "Toyota", "Highlander", 2008, "SUV", "Silver", 18555, 55060));
car_list.push(new Car(1543, "Ford", "Fusion", 2011, "Sedan", "Black", 13575, 90350));
car_list.push(new Car(1345, "Toyota", "Sienna", 2011, "Minivan", "Gray", 25775, 70000));
car_list.push(new Car(2133, "Dodge", "Caravan", 2012, "Minivan", "Red", 30250, 17567));
car_list.push(new Car(2999, "Lexus", "LFA", 2012, "coupe", "Red", 381370, 3500));
car_list.push(new Car(3001, "Ferrari", "Rubino", 2012, "coupe", "Red", 354370, 5500));
car_list.push(new Car(4002, "Audi", "R8", 2012, "SUV", "Black", 181370, 4500));


//Step-2 (a): call displayDropdown() function to set up the drop down selection list
displayDropdown();

//Step-2 (d): use jQuery event method .on() to add an event handler to the drop down list
//so that when users change selection option based on car type, 
//then only that type of cars will be displayed in the car list table in the web page.
$('#car-category').on('change', function(){
 var cat = $(this).val();
 console.log(cat);
 displayListing(cat);
} );


/*****************************/
/* displayDropdown()         */
/*****************************/ 
function displayDropdown(){
 var currentCat = 'select';
 var output = "<option value=\'"+ currentCat + "\'>Select a category to display</option>";
 var addedCats = [];

//Step-3 (a): add script code here to add options to the drop down list
 for(var i = 0; i < car_list.length; i++) {
  currentCat = car_list[i].type;
  //check whether the car's type has been included in the drop down list, if not, then add that category to the list
  //Array.indexOf(currentItem) is used to check whether currentItem is in the array, if not, then -1 will be returned.
  if (addedCats.indexOf(currentCat)==-1) { //did not find currentCat in addedCats array
   addedCats.push(currentCat); //add currentCat to addedCats array, and then create
   //an <option> element for that category
   output += "<option value='" + currentCat + "'  class='cat-select'>" + currentCat + "</option>";
//console.log("added " + currentCat);
  } 
//console.log(addedCats);
 } // end for loop
 //add one more category as an <option> element which is used to display all products 
 currentCat = "All";
 output += "<option value='" + currentCat + "'  class='cat-select'>" + currentCat + "</option>";
// output is a string used to hold all new <option> elements 
 $('#car-category').html(output);

 }
 
/*****************************/
/* displayListing()          */
/*****************************/  
 function displayListing(cat){
 //Step-2 (b): Add jQuery code in this function to remove class "hide" from car list table.  
 $('#car-list').removeClass('hide');
 var displayAll = false;
 if (cat == "All") {
  displayAll = true;
 } 
 if (cat == "select") {
   $('#car-list tbody').html("");
 }
 var body="";
 
   //add table body 
   //step-2 (c):add js code to complete the for loop and if statement  to display car list in the web page according to 
   //users’ selection on car type
   for(var i = 0; i < car_list.length; i++) {
   //cahnge this to type instead of category
  if(car_list[i].type == cat || displayAll == true) {
   console.log("add table list: " + cat);
   body += "<tr class='car-item' id='l-"+ i + "'>";  
   body += car_list[i].display();
   body += "<td><button type='button' value='" + 
   i + "' class='btn btn-primary add-item'>Add</button></td>";  
   body += "</tr>";
  }
 }
 $('#car-list tbody').html(body);
 }

//define an array (global variable) to store indices of the items added to the shopping cart*/
 var cart = [];
 

//Step-3 (a): Apply jQuery event delegation technique to add event handler so that when users click Add buttons, 
//the selected cars will be added to the shopping cart without any duplication, 
//the selected cars’ information including stockid, make, model, price, quantity and type will be displayed 
//in the shopping cart list on the web page, the number of items in the shopping cart as well as the Checkout 
//invoice information including subtotal, tax, registration fee, and total amount will be updated.
 $('#car_list').on('click', '.add-item', function(){
       var index = $(this).val(); 
       if (cart.indexOf(index)== -1)
       {  cart.push(index); 
//console.log("Cart array is currently: " + cart);
       }
       addQty(index); 
       updateShoppingCart();} );
/****************/
/* addQty()     */
/****************/
function addQty(index) {
 car_list[index].qty++;
}


/*****************************/
/* updateShoppingCart()      */
/*****************************/
 function updateShoppingCart(){
//step 3(b): Add jQuery code in this function to remove class "hide" from shopping cart table, 
//and also from check out table. 
    $('#cart table').removeClass('hide');
 $('#checkout table').removeClass('hide');
 
//console.log("Cart array is currently: " + cart);
 //display shopping cart 
 displayCartItems();

 // update total items
 updateItemTotal();

 //Update final checkout data
 calculateCheckoutCost();

 }
 
 /**************************/
/* displayCartItems()     */
/**************************/
function displayCartItems(){
 /* use this method to display items in the shopping cart.
 This method should  redisplay the 'shopping cart'
 table when we add or delete items.*/
 // add each product to shopping cart
 var runError = true;
 var elm='';
 for (var i=0; i<cart.length; i++){
   //create a table row and add stockId, make, cost, quantity, and type info of the selected cars to the cart table
   elm += "<tr><td class=\'col-xs-1\'>"+ car_list[cart[i]].stockid + "</td>";
   elm += "<td class=\'col-xs-1\'>"+ car_list[cart[i]].make + "</td>";
   elm += "<td class=\'col-xs-1\'>"+ car_list[cart[i]].model + "</td>";
   elm += "<td class=\'col-xs-1\'>"+ car_list[cart[i]].price + "</td>";
   elm += "<td class=\'col-xs-1\'><input  type=\'text\' id=\'" + cart[i] + "\' name=\'qty-" + i +
   "\' size=\'1\' value=\'"+ car_list[cart[i]].qty + "\'></td>";
   elm += "<td class=\'col-xs-1\'>"+ car_list[cart[i]].type + "</td>";
   elm += "<td class=\'col-xs-1\'><button type=\'button\' value=\'" + i + "\' class=\'delete-item\'>Delete</button></td></tr>";
   runError = false; // = cart is not empty
 }
 if (runError) { //if cart is empty
  elm += "Your cart is empty.";
 }
 //step 3(d): add a jQuery selector 
//console.log(elm); 
 $('#mycart tbody').html(elm); // modify the table
}


/*****************************/
/* updateItemTotal()         */
/*****************************/
 function updateItemTotal(){
 // update the total items
 var total = cart.length;
 $('#items').text(total);
 } 

/*******************************/
/* calculateCheckoutCost()     */
/*******************************/
function calculateCheckoutCost(){

 //Display total number of cars in the cart 
 var taxRate = 0.06;
 var feeRate = 0.05;
 var subtotal = 0;
 var tax = 0;
 var fee = 0;
 var total = 0;
 
 //Calculate subtotal 
 var subtotal = 0;
 //step 6: add js code here to calculat subtotal, tax, fee, and total amount
 //display those information to web page by using jQuery selector, jQuery .text() method.
  
}
//Step-4: Apply jQuery event delegation technique to add event handler so that when users click Delete buttons 
//the selected cars will be removed from the shopping cart and removed from the shopping cart list in the web page as well. 
//Meanwhile, the number of items in the shopping cart as well as the Checkout invoice information including subtotal, tax, 
//registration fee, and total amount will be updated.





/*****************************/
/* deleteItemFromCart()      */
/*****************************/
 function deleteItemFromCart(index){
 /*  remove the element with a given index from the cart array and update shopping cart
  use splice() method, Syntax: array_name.splice(start, how many elements)
 The splice() method removes elements starting from 'start' positions. The second arguments defines the number of elements to be removed.
 */
   //step 3(f): add script to update the ordering quantity of selected car and use splice method to 
   //remove that selected car from the shopping cart.
    car_list[cart[index]].qty = 0;
 cart.splice(index, 1);
}

//Step-5: Apply jQuery event delegation technique to add event handler so that when users change the ordering 
//quantities of selected cars in the shopping list in the web page, 
//the ordering quantities of selected cars the Checkout invoice information including subtotal, tax, registration fee,
// and total amount will be updated. 





/*****************************/
/* updateCartItemQty()       */
/*****************************/
 function updateCartItemQty(input) {
 var value = 0;
 value = parseInt($("#" + input.id).val());

 var index = parseInt(input.id); 
 car_list[index].qty = value;
 
 }

 


 
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Auto Shop - Used Cars</title>
    <!--Include bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
 <!-- Include JQuery library --> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
 <!-- Include external js file (JQuery_auto_shop.js) here -->
<script src="JQuery_auto_shop.js"></script>

 <style>
   td{ padding: 5px; margin: 5px;}
  .addme { height: 28px; width: 80px; padding: 0; }
  .clm-label { background: #333; color: #fff;}
  .hide {display: none} 
 </style>
 
</head>
<body class='container'>
 <div class='col-md-9' >
    <h2>Choose a car type </h2> <!--drop down list -->
 <select id="car-category" name="car-category">
  <option value='null'>Loading....</option>
 </select>
 </div>
 <div class='col-md-9'>
    <h2>Car List</h2> <!-- car list -->
  <table class='table hide' id='car-list'>
  <thead><!--car list table header -->
  <tr class='clm-label'> 
     <th class='clm-label'>Stock ID</th>
     <th class='clm-label'>Make</th>
     <th class='clm-label'>Model</th>
     <th class='clm-label'>Year</th>
     <th class='clm-label'>Type</th>
     <th class='clm-label'>Color</th>
     <th class='clm-label'>Price</th>
     <th class='clm-label'>Mileage</th>
     <th class='clm-label'>Select</th>
   </tr>  
   </thead>
   <tbody id='car-list'><!--car list table body -->
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
 <div class='col-md-3' id="cart">
  <h2>Shopping Cart</h2>
  <div>You have <span id="items">0</span>  items in your Shopping Cart</div>
  <table class='table hide' id='mycart'><!--Shopping Cart list table -->
  <thead><!--table header -->
   <tr>
    <th class='clm-label'>Stock Id</th>
    <th class='clm-label'>Make</th>
    <th class='clm-label'>Model</th>
    <th class='clm-label'>Price</th>
    <th class='clm-label'>Quantity</th>
    <th class='clm-label'>Type</th>
    <th class='clm-label'></th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody><!--table body -->
  </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>

<div class='col-md-9' id="checkout">
    <h2>Check Out</h2>
 <table class='table hide' ><!--Check Out table -->
  <tr><th class='col-xs-4'>Subtotal: </th><td class='col-xs-2' id='sub-total'>0</td></tr>
  <tr><th class='col-xs-4'>Taxes (6%): </th><td class='col-xs-2' id='taxes'>0</td></tr>
  <tr><th class='col-xs-4'>Registration fee (5%): </th><td class='col-xs-2' id='registration'>0</td></tr>
  <tr><th class='col-xs-4'>Total due: </th><td class='col-xs-2' id='total'>0</td></tr>
 </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```